# React - pass object from Container Component to Presentational Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically add Components (based on ID from an array) into my Presentational Component. I'm new to all this so there is a possibility I'm making it way too difficult for myself.

Here's the code of my Container Component:

```
    class TemplateContentContainer extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super()

            this.fetchModule = this.fetchModule.bind(this)
            this.removeModule = this.removeModule.bind(this)
            this.renderModule = this.renderModule.bind(this)
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if(nextProps.addAgain !== this.props.addAgain) // prevent infinite loop
            this.fetchModule(nextProps.addedModule)
        }

        fetchModule(id) {
            this.props.dispatch(actions.receiveModule(id))
        }

        renderModule(moduleId) {
            let AddModule = "Modules.module" + moduleId
            return <AddModule/>

        }

        removeModule(moduleRemoved) {
            console.log('remove clicked' + moduleRemoved)
            this.props.dispatch(actions.removeModule(moduleRemoved))
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TemplateContent
                        addedModule={this.props.addedModule}
                        templateModules={this.props.templateModules}
                        removeModule={this.removeModule}
                        renderModule={this.renderModule}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

and the code of the Presentational Component:

```
    const TemplateContent = (props) => {

        let templateModules = props.templateModules.map((module, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
                {props.renderModule(module)}
                <button onClick={props.removeModule.bind(this, index)}>
                    remove
                </button>
            </li>
        ))

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {templateModules}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

the `renderModule` function returns object, but when it's being passed to the presentational Component it doesn't work anymore (unless it's passed as className for example then it returns object)

I'm importing the modules from modules folder where I export them all into `index.js` file

```
import * as Modules from '../components/modules'
```

Hope it makes sense, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Where is the code for: "Modules.module" + moduleId? I don't think this is "dynamically rendering". You are making things complex for yourself I guess. You should be using something as mentioned in this: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to restructure the files to make for an easier handling.

If your container components render would look like this:

```
   render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                  {this.props.templateModules.map(module => (
                   <ChildComponent onRemove={this.removeModule} module={module} />
                  )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Your child component can just handle the remove click and the displaying of the module data

**EDIT:**

My bad, I just misunderstood your problem.
I would map the ids to the according components instead of concatenating the name of the Component you want to render, so your container component would look something like this:

```
 getChildComponent (id) {
    const foo = {
      foo: () => {
        return <Foo onRemove={this.removeModule} />
      },
      bar: () => {
        return <Bar onRemove={this.removeModule} />
      }
    }

    return foo[id]
 }

 render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
               {this.props.templateModules.map(module => (
                 {this.getChildComponent(module.id)()}
               )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also you should maybe have a look at react-redux and move your dispatches to react-redux containers.

Comment: How would my child component look like then?

Comment: I mean even if i do module={this.renderModule(module)} in the Container Component it wouldn't insert object in my Child Component, in the dev tools I can only see <Modules.module1 /> which is correct but it doesn't pull the Component through

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully this captures your question more than before.